# Make select dropdown readonly and required

Tags: html

I have this Select and I don't understand why the `requiered` is not working as expected. I want it to be `readonly` and mandatory.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
<select class="form-control" id="UnidadMedida" readonly name="cbmUnidadMedida" required> 
                                <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                                <option value="Unidad">Unidad</option>
                                <option value="Kg">Kilogramo</option>
                                <option value="oz">Onzas</option>
                                <option value="l">Litro</option>
                                <option value="gal">Galon</option>
                                <option value="m">Metro</option>
                                <option value="min">Minuto</option>
                                <option value="h">Hora</option>
                                <option value="d">Dia</option>
                                <option value="ml">Mililitro</option>
                                <option value="g">Gramo</option>
                                <option value="t">Tonelada</option>
                                <option value="sp">Servicios Profesionales</option>
                                </select>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Html5 doesnot support `required` and `readonly`

The select tag in HTML doesn't have a `readonly attribute`, only a **disabled attribute.** So if you want to keep the user from changing the dropdown, you have to use **disabled** .

```html
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php" >
<select class="form-control" id="UnidadMedida"  required> 
                                <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                                <option value="Unidad">Unidad</option>
                                <option value="Kg">Kilogramo</option>
                                <option value="oz">Onzas</option>
                                <option value="l">Litro</option>
                                <option value="gal">Galon</option>
                                <option value="m">Metro</option>
                                <option value="min">Minuto</option>
                                <option value="h">Hora</option>
                                <option value="d">Dia</option>
                                <option value="ml">Mililitro</option>
                                <option value="g">Gramo</option>
                                <option value="t">Tonelada</option>
                                <option value="sp">Servicios Profesionales</option>
                                </select>
<input type="submit">
</form>



</body>
```

here for only (required) select tag

Answer (score 0):

there is no `readonly` attribute for selects in HTML. I don't know if you meant `disabled` or something :(

Here you can check the valid attributes:
[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)